# SimpleDateFormat showing minutes, seconds and milliseconds wrong

Tags: java, datetime, simpledateformat

I have written this sample program where I want to convert a date into another format. I don't see the expected date when using simple date format.

```
 public class TestDate {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat originalformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.SSSSSS");
        SimpleDateFormat targetformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");
        try {

            //Use Simple Date Format
            Date date = originalformat.parse("2015-04-09-17.18.48.677862");
            System.out.println("Using SDF "+targetformat.format(date));

            //Use Manual Translation
            String eventTime = "2015-04-09-17.18.48.677862";
            StringBuffer timeBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i = 0; i < eventTime.length(); i++) {
                if (i == 10) {
                    timeBuffer.append(" ");
                    continue;
                } else if (i == 13 || i == 16) {
                    timeBuffer.append(":");
                    continue;
                } else {
                    timeBuffer.append(eventTime.charAt(i));
                }
            }
            timeBuffer.append("000");
            String transformedTime = timeBuffer.toString().trim();
            System.out.println("Manual Translation "+transformedTime);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

I see the following outputs. The first logic is using simple date format and the second one is manual translation.

```
Using SDF 2015-04-09 17:30:05.000862
Manual Translation 2015-04-09 17:18:48.677862000
```

So How to make the simple date format to output a exactly similar value like the manual one

Comment: You've specified 677862 milliseconds, which is 677 seconds... if you're going to specify a millisecond value, it should be 3 digits, not 6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would appear that you can't use 6 digits for the milliseconds. Your program is 11 minutes and 17 seconds off. 660 seconds = 11 minutes and you have 17 seconds off. So its just converting your input into minutes from seconds since it can't accept more than 3 milliseconds digits.

Answer (score 6):

The value `677862` is being interpreted as milliseconds, as per the [`SimpleDateFormat` javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), not as microseconds.  That is 677 seconds, 862 milliseconds.  The seconds part is 11 minutes and 17 seconds, which is added to `17.18.48` to become `17.30.05`.

To work with the `S` format, you will need 3 digits for the milliseconds, not 6.  You will need to truncate your string to 3 digits past the last decimal point.